# Math.sin() behaving strangely in javascript

Tags: javascript

For some reason when I input Math.PI and 3.14 I get completely different and even impossible results

Edit: Nevermind, I'm just dumb and didn't notice the e-16

Comment: 3.14 is just a **round number** of PI, so results of Math.sin() will be different

Comment: `Math.PI - 3.14 === 0.0015926535897929917`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives ~10^-16 something very close to zero you can

```js
console.log(Math.sin(Math.PI).toFixed(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have set up a test of your problem

```js
console.log(Math.sin(3.14));
console.log(Math.sin(Math.PI));
```

When run, I get this result:

```
0.0015926529164868282
1.2246467991473532e-16
```

The 2nd number is a really really small positive number. It is essentially 0. The first number is slightly larger, but 3.14 is a rounded value of PI, and that's why you get the difference